# How to access index, key and value in Python

Tags: python

I have a generator:

```
def get_items(self):
        for item in self.info.get_data():
            item = {
                '_name': item.name,
                '_email': item.email,
            }
            yield item
```

I want to iterate over this generator, assign index to each item key, and then store them in a dict like so:

```
items = ['item_0_name': 'example name', 'item_0_email': 'example@email.com', 
         'item_1_name': 'Some name', 'item_1_email': 'ex@mail.com' ....]
```

I use enumerate to get index, but then I can't access item's key to add index to it:

```
items = []
for i, item in enumerate(self.get_items()):
    items['item_'.join(str(i)).join(self.get_items()[i])] = item
```

But then I'm getting:

```
TypeError: 'generator' object has no attribute '__getitem__
```

Is there any Pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
items = []
for i, item in enumerate(self.get_items()):
    items.append({'item_{}{}'.format(i, k): v for k, v in item.iteritems()})
```

List demo:

```
In [54]: for i, j in enumerate(get_items(test)):
    items.append({'item_{}{}'.format(i, k): v for k, v in j.iteritems()})
   ....:     

In [55]: items
Out[55]: 
[{'item_0_email': 'example@email.com', 'item_0_name': 'example_name'},
 {'item_1_email': 'ex@email.com', 'item_1_name': 'Some name'}]
```

I assume that what you actually want to do is to append these dictionaries to a list, because, well, `items` is defined as a list. Otherwise if you want to add these to a dictionary, do the following:

```
items = {} # Items is now a dictionary
for i, item in enumerate(self.get_items()):
    items.update({'item_{}{}'.format(i, k): v for k, v in item.iteritems()})
```

Dictionary demo

```
In [56]: items = {}

In [57]: for i, j in enumerate(get_items(test)):
    items.update({'item_{}{}'.format(i, k): v for k, v in j.iteritems()})
   ....:     

In [58]: items
Out[58]: 
{'item_0_email': 'example@email.com',
 'item_0_name': 'example_name',
 'item_1_email': 'ex@email.com',
 'item_1_name': 'Some name'}
```

Remember that `self.get_items()` yields *dictionaries*. That means you'll have to deal with all of the items in the dictionary. And the above methods are doing exactly that.

The code uses [`dict comprehensions`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). They are like list comprehensions but, in this case, iterate over the keys and values of the each dictionary that the `self.get_items()` generator yields.

Comment: Well seen, the OP is clearly unclear on whether `items` is a list or a dictionary. That makes a big difference to the algorithm to use ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The error you get is due to the fact that `self.get_items()` is a generator, and such objects do not permit to do such thing as `self.get_items()[1]` because in terms of meaning, there is no history.

But in your case, you just missed that `self.get_items()` yields one dict at each call. You just have to make use of that dict:

```
items = []
for i, item_dict in enumerate(self.get_items()):
    for key, item in item_dict:
        items['item_{0}{1}'.format(i, key)] = item
```

By the way, you have another strong error (that I did not correct in my example above): `items` is a list, so your attempt to do `items[some_not_yet_defined_string] = something` will fail, first because the index is of `str` type, and second because you cannot append stuff to list by specifying new indexes.

Moreover, your call to `'item_'.join(str(i)).join [...]` is not what you expect: `str.join(iterable)` returns a string made of the iterable items separated by the given `str`. It's not generating multiple strings, and will surely not generate several keys for your `items` dict.